# ¿Cómo dibujo una curva bezier en bing maps con WPF y C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando dibujar una curva tipo bezier en el componente bing maps para wpf con c#, pero no hay componentes para dibujar una curva entre dos puntos con puntos intermedios.

¿Algún consejo para dibujar una linea curva de una Location x a una y?

Comment: Tiene que ser bezier? No te vale una [Polilinea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg427597.aspx)?

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobre impresionar una curva Bezier definiendo sus 4 puntos:

```
Point p1(10, 100);   // Inicio
Point c1(100, 10);   // primer punto de control
Point c2(150, 150);  // segundo punto de control
Point p2(200, 100);  // final
Pen pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
graphics.DrawBezier(&pen, p1, c1, c2, p2);
```

Aunque es mejor opción para realizar la trayectoria entre dos puntos en el mapa indicar si es ruta a pie, coche... en este blog tienes en detalle ejemplos:

https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/drawing-dashed-routes-behind-buildings-in-birds-eyes/

Y una lista de ejemplos online: 
http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Directions_Basic